# Recursively destroy contents of jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, destructor

My code opens a jQuery UI dialog and uses AJAX to load the content. Several other widgets are being initialized inside the dialog. When the dialog is closed, I destroy() and remove() it's div, but it does not destroy the widgets inside.

How do I properly remove all elements inside mydiv on dialog close?

```
// mydiv contains variable content
mydiv.dialog({

    autoOpen: true,
    close: function(){
        // destroy mydiv and all widgets inside it

        mydiv.dialog('destroy').remove();

        alert('Unfortunatelly, inner dialog remained. How to get rid of ALL widgets placed inside "mydiv?"');
        // How do i destroy everything inside?
    }        
});
```

Interactive sample: http://jsfiddle.net/r4cHY/4/

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that earlier versions of jQuery / jQuery UI worked fine with my example.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. The implementation of jQuery UI dialog removes the designated  completely out of it's parent and moves it inside  where it can be positioned better. Unfortunately there is no longer link between the context of the dialog where it was opened and the widget, that's why destroying content can't affect the dialog.

Better fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gxXBY/

This leads to all sorts of negative effects inside a complex UI system and I believe is a bug in jQuery UI. Here is a fix:

```
var oldcr = $.ui.dialog.prototype._create;
$.ui.dialog.prototype._create = function(){
    var self=this;
    $('<div/>').insertBefore(this.element).on('remove',function(){
        self.element.remove();
    });
    oldcr.apply(this,arguments);
};
```

Add this inside your javascript anywhere and it will fix all the dialogs. Worked perfectly for me.